# Union two tables with different dates based on column value?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, union

We switched to a new platform on Jan 1 and I need to union two tables to get a data source with the old data and new data combined. However, some accounts had to be switched out of the old platform before Jan 1.

The new data table has data from December for all accounts but I only want to use the new December data where there is no old December data. How can I union the new data with most accounts data starting on Jan 1 but also with the outlier few accounts starting on the proper day in December?

Ex: For Account1 I need new data starting Jan 1; for Account2 I need new data from Dec 30; for Account 3 I need new data from Dec 31

```
Old Table  
------------------------------------   
Account         Date         Sales  
------------------------------------
Account1        12-29-18     10  
Account1        12-30-18     10  
Account1        12-31-18     5  
Account2        12-29-18     10    
Account3        12-29-18     20  
Account3        12-30-18     10

New Table
------------------------------------   
Account         Date         Sales  
------------------------------------
Account1        12-29-18     10  
Account1        12-30-18     10  
Account1        12-31-18     5  
Account1        01-01-19     20  
Account2        12-30-18     15  
Account2        12-31-18     20  
Account2        01-01-19     10  
Account3        12-30-18     10  
Account3        12-31-18     20  
Account3        01-01-19     5  

Output
------------------------------------   
Account         Date         Sales  
------------------------------------
Account1        12-29-18     10  
Account1        12-30-18     10  
Account1        12-31-18     5  
Account1        01-01-19     20  
Account2        12-29-18     10
Account2        12-30-18     15  
Account2        12-31-18     20  
Account2        01-01-19     10
Account3        12-29-18     20  
Account3        12-30-18     10
Account3        12-31-18     20  
Account3        01-01-19     5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
  #standardSQL
  SELECT account, date, 
    ARRAY_AGG(sales ORDER BY data LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] sales
  FROM (
    SELECT 'old' data, * FROM `project.dataset.old_table` UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'new' data, * FROM `project.dataset.new_table` 
  )
  GROUP BY account, date
```

You can test, play with above using example data from your question as

```
  #standardSQL
  WITH `project.dataset.old_table` AS (
    SELECT 'Account1' account, '12-29-18' date, 10 sales UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'Account1', '12-30-18', 10 UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'Account1', '12-31-18', 5 UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'Account2', '12-29-18', 10 UNION ALL    
    SELECT 'Account3', '12-29-18', 20 UNION ALL  
    SELECT 'Account3', '12-30-18', 10 
  ),  `project.dataset.new_table` AS (
    SELECT 'Account1' account, '12-29-18' date, 10 sales UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account1', '12-30-18', 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account1', '12-31-18', 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account1', '01-01-19', 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account2', '12-30-18', 15 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account2', '12-31-18', 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account2', '01-01-19', 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account3', '12-30-18', 10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account3', '12-31-18', 20 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Account3', '01-01-19', 5 
  )
  SELECT account, date, 
    ARRAY_AGG(sales ORDER BY data LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] sales
  FROM (
    SELECT 'old' data, * FROM `project.dataset.old_table` UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'new' data, * FROM `project.dataset.new_table` 
  )
  GROUP BY account, date
  ORDER BY account, PARSE_DATE('%m-%d-%y', date)
```

with result

```
Row account     date        sales    
1   Account1    12-29-18    10   
2   Account1    12-30-18    10   
3   Account1    12-31-18    5    
4   Account1    01-01-19    20   
5   Account2    12-29-18    10   
6   Account2    12-30-18    15   
7   Account2    12-31-18    20   
8   Account2    01-01-19    10   
9   Account3    12-29-18    20   
10  Account3    12-30-18    10   
11  Account3    12-31-18    20   
12  Account3    01-01-19    5
```

Comment: This got the job done, thanks a lot!

I have a couple questions if you could clarify for me. What exactly does the ARRAY_AGG function do? I've looked it up but having trouble understanding. 

Also, why does ordering by the data limit to the 'old' data? Wouldn't ordering by data then limiting it use the 'new' data since alphabetically 'new' would be on top after ordering?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Commenting again to make sure you see the editing comment above

Comment: `ARRAY_AGG` with `GROUP BY` aggregates all `sales` by `account, date` then orders the array by data and then leaves only the top element.  finally `OFFSET(0)` takes that first (and only) element out of array